# docker deamon.json no logs on Win11 WSL

Tags: docker, logging, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have enabled logs for docker but not getting any when I set two terminals and I pull e.g. redis. I would expect some logs about the pull process, e.g. execute a POST for redis service to docker hub.

I'm on Windows 11 wsl.

Terminal 1 for Logs:

```
sergio@Home-Win11:~$ cat /etc/docker/deamon.json
{"debug": true}
sergio@Home-Win11:~$ sudo service docker restart
[sudo] password for sergio:
sergio@Home-Win11:~$ sudo journalctl -f -u docker
Sep 28 06:17:09 Home-Win11 dockerd[879]: time="2023-09-28T06:17:09.208588284+01:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Sep 28 06:17:09 Home-Win11 dockerd[879]: time="2023-09-28T06:17:09.667280219+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Sep 28 06:17:09 Home-Win11 dockerd[879]: time="2023-09-28T06:17:09.690214389+01:00" level=warning msg="WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_bps_device support"
Sep 28 06:17:09 Home-Win11 dockerd[879]: time="2023-09-28T06:17:09.690241320+01:00" level=warning msg="WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_bps_device support"
Sep 28 06:17:09 Home-Win11 dockerd[879]: time="2023-09-28T06:17:09.690244200+01:00" level=warning msg="WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_iops_device support"
Sep 28 06:17:09 Home-Win11 dockerd[879]: time="2023-09-28T06:17:09.690245904+01:00" level=warning msg="WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_iops_device support"
Sep 28 06:17:09 Home-Win11 dockerd[879]: time="2023-09-28T06:17:09.690255314+01:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=1a79695 graphdriver=overlay2 version=24.0.6
Sep 28 06:17:09 Home-Win11 dockerd[879]: time="2023-09-28T06:17:09.690277500+01:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Sep 28 06:17:09 Home-Win11 dockerd[879]: time="2023-09-28T06:17:09.706417503+01:00" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
Sep 28 06:17:09 Home-Win11 systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
```

In the second terminal after having entered journalctl in the first terminal:

```
sergio@Home-Win11:~$ docker pull redis
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/redis
Digest: sha256:ae51486efeea8a9b3f85542e408f79a5012d5b7fa35ae19733104ecc6992a248
Status: Image is up to date for redis:latest
docker.io/library/redis:latest
sergio@Home-Win11:~$
```